# Getting dependency service object null in helper class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have created one helper class and injected one service in this way, but when I try to call function from that service object then getting error like service was null.

```
 public class LogHelper
    {
        public CommonServiceType _service;

        public LogHelper(CommonServiceType service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }

        public async void AddLog()
        {

            httpResponseMessage = await _service.SendData();
        }
}
```

But here _service I am getting null and getting error on _service was null

Comment: Is `LogHelper` resolved from the DI container? Is `CommonServiceType` registered with that DI container also? If so, show your code; this question is currently unanswerable.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay CommonServiceType is registered in this way : services.AddScoped<CommonServiceType>();  And LogHelper from where I can make it resolved with DI..should I add this class also in startup class ?

Comment: `LogHelper` should be resolved as a dependency of another DI registered type (via the constructor) or manually using `ServiceProvider.GetService()`. If you manually instantiate it, then how could the `CommonServiceType` dependency be resolved?

Comment: Did you register the LogHelper is the DI container or not?

Comment: Please upgrade your question to a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This means, provide us with a fully runnable program with the *minimum amount of code possible* that demonstrates the problem. There is currently too little information for us to provide you with answers why this is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have same kind of issue happen earlier..

My problem was I was not passing object when I try to call function. So I did in below way and it worked for me.

```
LogHelper log = new LogHelper(_yourserviceobject);
log.callfunction()
```